# What is included after Hit: in monster attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack

So, in the most recent session our DM sicced a hobgoblin tribe on us, and it was controlling a souped up [hellfire engine](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/94967-hellfire-engine) (it was immune to force damage, had a speed 80 so we could not outrun it, and the cannon had a range of 1000 feet, so we could not deal with it at a distance with our longbow).

In the fight with this monster, he argued that only the first sentence of an attack after *Hit:* is dependent on a hit. He claims because there is a full stop after that, the rest of the effect is separate and always happens, hit or no hit.

So he wanted to apply the bolded section below to electrocute us, after he missed with an attack due to one of us diving behind cover and casting *shield*.

> **Lightning Flail**. Melee Weapon Attack: +11 to hit, reach 15 ft., one creature. *Hit:* 18 (3d8 + 5) bludgeoning damage plus 22 (5d8) lightning damage. **Up to three other creatures of the hellfire engine’s choice that it can see within 30 feet of the target must each make a DC 20 Dexterity saving throw, taking 22 (5d8) lightning damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.**

I believe that all the text after *Hit:* in an attack action is dependent on the attack hitting. Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate of the same question about a different stat block.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Fine with me, had not seen that

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin If you are satisfied with an answer provided, you can accept it even if the question is closed.

Comment: @Eddymage done, thank you for the clear and well documented answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You are right.

The DMG provides [guidance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#MeleeandRangedAttacks) on how to read the attacks' description:

> **Hit.** Any damage dealt or other effects that occur as a result of an attack hitting a target are described after the “Hit” notation. [...]
>
> **Miss.** If an attack has an effect that occurs on a miss, that information is presented after the “Miss:” notation.

Since there is no **Miss** notation\$^1\$ in the description of the attack, each effect described after the *Hit* notation occurs on a hit.

---

If it was not so, some attacks would not have much sense and could be quite powerful: for example, consider the [Ghoul](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16872-ghoul)'s Claws attack:

> **Claws.** Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 7 (2d4 + 2) slashing damage. If the target is a creature other than an elf or undead, it must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or be paralyzed for 1 minute. The target can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.

If the paralysis takes place even on a miss, each attack has a chance to paralyze the enemy, which is not the case.

---

\$^1\$ There are few monsters with this notation: I found two for now, the [Piercer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17191-piercer) and the [Kobold Inventor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17277-kobold-inventor).

Comment: Here is the GM ;-)

The way I imagined the description was that  the massive flail of a gargantuan construct plunges down targeting a specific enemy, then swirls around, even if it has not hit that enemy, dealing a kind of area damage, that could affect multiple creatures because the swirling is sort of a horizontal movement.

I guess the idea arose from the fact that the way the description of the secondary damage is written seems entirely unrelated to the primary damage. So the primary damage affect one creature, and the secondary affects multiples.

Comment: If the primary misses, why could the swirling not happen and the area effect play out in any case.

I recognise that this interpretation might be against RAW, but usually the logic of secondary damage is related to the primary one, and is some logical consequence of it. I can't recall having Sen any examples where the secondary damage targets entirely different creatures with a different type of attack on top (save DC vs Melee attack). 

I’m aware I could have houseruled it but I am a fan of RAW generally…

Comment: @vlysses Hi there! Actually, the rules are pretty clear: the secondary damage happens if and only if the attack is successful. As a comparison, beside the two monsters provided in the answer, you can also have a look at the [*Acid Arrow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/acid-arrow) spell: *On a miss, the arrow splashes the target with acid for half as much of the initial damage and no damage at the end of its next turn*. I totally understand your reasoning and it sounds quite convincing: remember that as a DM you can homebrew monsters and their abilities as it suits you best.

Comment: Ty @eddymage - I think we are not necessarily in disagreement, but again, I maintain that you example is very different. It details exactly what happens in case of a miss etc… in the organically example, there is a full stop after the initial damage, then a completely new description starts that affect other creatures and is determined differently, without any connection to the primary damage whatsoever, except that it’s in the same attack block. I could make the argument that in the acid arrow example the way damage is dealt and calculated is described precisely.

Comment: Cont.: while in the Hellfire engine, this is exactly not the case, it’s an entirely different sentence without any relation to the previous outcome. You only infer from the fact that it’s written within the same attack block description that it’s sort of part of that attack. Are there no other examples of 2 independent damages as a result of the same attack in the entire d&d system…? 

Comment: @vlysses You can rule that way if you want, but the rules are pretty unambiguous here about what’s supposed to happen. An attack only has an effect on a miss if its description has a “*Miss:*” section.

Comment: @vlysses The *ice knife* spell from Xanathar's hits twice off a single attack, and it's extremely clear about it: "Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 piercing damage.  Hit or miss, the shard then explodes. The target and each creature within 5 feet of it must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 2d6 cold damage." There's no ambiguity or implied "new description".  It says right there, "hit or miss".

Comment: To me, the description implies it hits one guy with the flail, then then lighting zaps him and jumps in big electric arcs to other targets in range. If the initial attack misses, the electricity all goes into the ground, I suppose. I don't get the 'swirls around' thing, since that would imply the flail suddenly becomes up to 30' longer than the initial attack's reach.